# How to read lines from a text file but exclude lines including specific words with python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that counts the amount of tweets a user has made, reading from a text file. The only problem is that I need to exclude any lines with the words "DM" or "RT".

```
file = open('stream.txt', 'r')
fileread = file.readlines()
tweets = [string.split() for string in fileread]
```

How can I change my code to make sure it excludes the lines with "DM" or "RT"?

All help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always close your file after opening it. Best way to do that is by using `with open(...)`

The solution to your answer is putting a condition in your list comprehension:

```
with open('stream.txt', 'r') as file:
    fileread = file.readlines()

tweets = [string.split() for string in fileread 
          if not "DM" in string and not "RT" in string]
```

In case you want to exlude several strings, you can use `any` to save space at some point:

```
with open('stream.txt', 'r') as file:
    fileread = file.readlines()

exclude = ["DM", "RT"]
tweets = [string.split() for string in fileread 
          if not any(exclude[j] in string for j in range(len(exclude)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter out lines which contain `'DM'` and `'RT'` when you declare `fileread`:

```
fileread = [l for l in file.readlines() if not 'DM' in l and not 'RT' in l]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately my code is still not working and I'm really not sure why. Am I meant to replace my second line completely with the one you commented? Because it still seems to be counting the lines with DM and RT

Comment: @kmurp62rulz Yes, you need to replace your second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over each row in file:

```
tweets = list()
with open('stream.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "DM" not in line and "RT" not in line:
            tweets.append(line.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise solution (since you seem to appreciate lists by comprehension ;-)

```
file = open('stream.txt', 'r')
fileread = file.readlines()
goodlines = [lines for lines in fileread if lines[:2]!="DM" and lines[:2]!="RT"]
tweets = [string.split() for string in goodlines]
```

goodlines acts as a filter, keeping lines of fileread if the first two caracters are different from 'DM' and 'RT'. (If I understood your problem correctly)